# Jest -- Mock a function called inside a React Component

Tags: unit-testing, reactjs, mocking, jestjs

Jest provides a way to mock functions as described in their docs

```js
apiGetMethod = jest.fn().mockImplementation(
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const userID = parseInt(url.substr('/users/'.length), 10);
        process.nextTick(
            () => users[userID] ? resolve(users[userID]) : reject({
                error: 'User with ' + userID + ' not found.',
            });
        );
    });
);
```

However these mocks only seem to work when the function is called directly in a test.

```js
describe('example test', () => {
    it('uses the mocked function', () => {
        apiGetMethod().then(...);
    });
});
```

If I have a React Component defined as such how can I mock it?

```js
import { apiGetMethod } from './api';

class Foo extends React.Component {
    state = {
        data: []
    }

    makeRequest = () => {
       apiGetMethod().then(result => {
           this.setState({data: result});
       });
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        this.makeRequest();
    }

    render() {
        return (
           <ul>
             { this.state.data.map((data) => <li>{data}</li>) }
           </ul>
        )   
    }
}
```

I have no idea how to make it so `Foo` component calls my mocked `apiGetMethod()` implementation so that I can test that it renders properly with data.

(this is a simplified, contrived example for the sake of understanding how to mock functions called inside react components)

edit: api.js file for clarity

```js
// api.js
import 'whatwg-fetch';

export function apiGetMethod() {
   return fetch(url, {...});
}
```

Comment: How is `apiGetMethod` injected into your module?

Comment: `import { apiGetMethod } from './api';` at the top of the `Foo` component file

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You have to mock the `./api` module like this and import it so you can set the implemenation of the mock

```js
import { apiGetMethod } from './api'

jest.mock('./api', () => ({ apiGetMethod: jest.fn() }))
```

in your test can set how the mock should work using [mockImplementation](http://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/mock-function-api.html#mockfnmockimplementationfn):

```js
apiGetMethod.mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve('test1234'))
```

Comment: I was following the creation of the mock by putting it in `__mocks__/api.js` and then calling `jest.mock('./api')` but it doesn't pull the mock, I was following https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/tutorial-async.html#content

Comment: In what file is this line: `jest.mock('./api', () => ({ apiGetMethod: jest.fn() }))`? In the test?

Comment: @YPCrumble yes in the test file

Comment: What if, in the above example, you want to mock or spy on `makeRequest`? I'm writing a similar test where I just want to test how often `makeRequest` is fired. Is that possible? (I don't care about what's in `makeRequest` in this case.

Answer (score 8):

In case the `jest.mock` method from @Andreas's answer did not work for you. you could try the following in your test file.

```js
const api = require('./api');
api.apiGetMethod = jest.fn(/* Add custom implementation here.*/);
```

This should execute your mocked version of the `apiGetMethod` inside you `Foo` component.

Comment: This is actually what I ended up doing, mocking the implementation inside: `jest.fn(() => { return ... })`

Comment: Can you show the fanilly code here, I have the same problem, thx @RyanCastner

Answer (score 7):

Here is an updated solution for anyone struggling with this in '21. This solution uses **Typescript**, so be aware of that. For regular JS just take out the type calls wherever you see them.

You import the function inside your test at the top

`import functionToMock from '../api'`

Then you indeed mock the call to the **folder** outside of the tests, to indicate that anything being called from this folder should and will be mocked

```
[imports are up here]

jest.mock('../api');

[tests are down here]
```

Next we mock the actual function we're importing. Personally I did this inside the test, but I assume it works just as well outside the test or inside a `beforeEach`

`(functionToMock as jest.Mock).mockResolvedValue(data_that_is_returned);`

Now here's the kicker and where everyone seems to get stuck. So far this is correct, but we are missing one important bit when mocking functions inside a component: `act`. You can read more on it [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/testing-recipes.html#act) but essentially we want to wrap our render inside this act. React testing library has it's own version of `act`. It is also asynchronous, so you have to make sure your test is async and also define the destructured variables from `render` outside of it.

In the end your test file should look something like this:

```
import { render, act } from '@testing-library/react';
import UserGrid from '../components/Users/UserGrid';
import { data2 } from '../__fixtures__/data';
import functionToMock from '../api';

jest.mock('../api');

describe("Test Suite", () => {
  it('Renders', async () => {
    (functionToMock as jest.Mock).mockResolvedValue(data2);

    let getAllByTestId: any;
    let getByTestId: any;
    await act(async () => {
      ({ getByTestId, getAllByTestId } = render(<UserGrid />));
    });
    const container = getByTestId('grid-container');
    const userBoxes = getAllByTestId('user-box');
  });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Another solution to mock this would be:

```js
window['getData'] = jest.fn();
```