# Mocking a function inside a component under test Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, react-testing-library

Can we mock a function which is written inside the component under test in Reactjs?

Comment: I think this can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43500235/jest-mock-a-function-called-inside-a-react-component

Comment: Thanks @AmirhosseinRahmati for replying. I already saw this one but that didn't help me.

Comment: I don't think you can mock the function written inside a react component. You'll have to refactor it outside to mock it.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly mock a function but there are ways you could get it working. You could pass the function in props and call that instead of using the original function.

For example

```
const MyComponent = () => {
   const myFunction = () => {
      // Your code here
   };
   // rest of the code
}
```

You can turn this into

```
const MyComponent = ({myMockedFunction}) => {
   const myFunction = myMockedFunction || (() => {
      // Your code here
   });
   // rest of the code
}
```

Other ways include refactoring the function outside so you can use jest.mock directly.